# Excel formula problem: The formula adds one day to the total number of days when the total number of hours is 12, not 24

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that converts days to Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds but it adds one day to the total number of days when the total number of hours is 12, not 24.

This is the formula:

`=INT(H20/365)&" Years, "&INT(MOD(H20;365)/30)&" Months, "&ROUND(MOD((MOD(H20;365));30);0)&" Days,  "&INT((H20-INT(H20))*24)& " Hours,  "&INT((((H20-INT(H20))*24)-INT((H20-INT(H20))*24))*60)&" Minutes, "&ROUNDDOWN((((((H20-INT(H20))*24)-INT((H20-INT(H20))*24))*60)-INT(((((H20-INT(H20))*24)-INT((H20-INT(H20))*24))*60)))*60;0)&" Seconds"`

This is what it displays:

> 0 Years, 0 Months, 8 Days, 12 Hours, 53 Minutes, 7 Seconds

Although I have 7 Days and 12 Hours. It continues to display 8 days and the corresponding number of hours until it reaches 24 hours, after which the hours return to 0 and the days remain at 8. Although at the moment when the hours return to 0, the days should be incremented by one, but they remain because they were increased when the hours were 12.

I spent a long time trying to find the error, but without success. And the function of the formula is from a decimal number corresponding to a certain number of days, the formula to convert them into Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds. Such as from 497.245253 days to convert them to 1 Years, 4 Months, 12 Days, 5 Hours, 53 Minutes, 7 Seconds.

Comment: Please note that your definition of Years and Months is arbitrary, since each of them can have a varying number of days. I also don't understand why you compute `7` seconds as a result vs `10` seconds (or `9`).   `0.245253 => 05:53:09.859`

Answer (score 0):

In the part of the formula calculating the number of days, you need to use `ROUNDDOWN` instead of `ROUND`.

You could also use the Excel functions `HOUR`, `MINUTE` and `SECOND` to simplify this formula greatly.

Comment: I appreciate your response Neil! It worked with the ROUNDDOWN formula